# Wordpress getting css and script files from client machine rather than the server machine

Tags: javascript, css

I'm a noob Wordpress user and I'm having an odd problem. I managed to install Wordpress edit the wp-config file and everything.

However when I browse my site from a remote machine no css or script files are loaded, although I can see the html page without any styling.

When I checked the source, I found out that Wordpress is trying to get the scirpt files from the client machine ex: *http://127.0.0.1/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css?ver=20111208*

Any Ideas on what the problem might be ?

Comment: Is that a theme you're creating or something you've downloaded somewhere? Usually css and javascript files are called with some built-in functions such as bloginfo: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 1):

in **Settings** > **General**

Have your **Wordpress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** settings been updated?

[image]